# Make the rectangle keep moving towards the direction i give to him

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a snake game but I'm using rectangle not snake actually, I can't make the rectangle keep moving towards the direction i give to him it just move one when i press it ,So i want to make it keep moving how to do it .

that is the code :

```
def keys ():

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for i in range(2):
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            # rect.move_ip(0,-3)
            rect2.move_ip(0, -3)
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            # rect.move_ip(0,3)
            rect2.move_ip(0, 3)
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            # rect.move_ip(-3,0)
            rect2.move_ip(-3, 0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            # rect.move_ip(3,0)
            rect2.move_ip(3, 0)
```

Comment: add a while inside the movements, and stop it when you enter a new key

Comment: @Raskayu how can i make it

Comment: when i put a while loop there is nothing to show in the window

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rectangle to continue moving, even when no button is pressed, I would recommend a `speed` variable.  Two, actually, you will need an `x_speed` and a `y_speed`.

```
x_speed = y_speed = 0
x_location = y_location = 0

def keys():
    global x_speed
    global y_speed
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for i in range(2):
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            y_speed = 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y_speed = -3
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x_speed = -3
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x_speed = 3

while True:
    keys()
    x_location += x_speed
    y_location += y_speed
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, COLOR, (x_location, y_location, WIDTH, HEIGHT))
```

By using `x_speed` and `y_speed`, the main loop will "remember" that it's moving, and only stop or change when it recognizes input.  The main loop simply adds `*_speed` to `*_location` every iteration, then calculates the speed for the next iteration.